# How to configure SAM CLI to use remote docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, debugging, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

My host operating system is windows 10 and I have installed ubuntu 20.04 focal with the help of WSL2.

My goal is to debug sam application without using Docker Desktop

I have installed docker daemon on the Ubuntu Linux distro with the help of the link below.
[How to run docker on windows without using docker desktop](https://dev.to/_nicolas_louis_/how-to-run-docker-on-windows-without-docker-desktop-hik)

Now I want to debug the sam application that I have developed on my local machine and I want to use dockerd installed on ubuntu.

To launch docked on ubuntu, I use the following command.

```
sudo dockerd -H `ifconfig eth0 | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -f2 -d:`
```

As result, I will get the IP address to interact with dockerd

INFO[2021-12-31T10:31:12.959579412+05:30] API listen on 172.17.52.120:2375

For CLI, I am using [Docker CLI](https://github.com/StefanScherer/docker-cli-builder/releases)

To test whether dockerd is working or not, I use the following command

```
docker -H 172.20.5.64 run --rm hello-world
```

**How can I tell sam cli to use the dockerd running inside ubuntu while invoking `sam local invoke` command?**

Comment: This is an incredibly insecure setup: anyone who can reach the Docker socket can pretty trivially root the host, and you've made that unrestricted unauthenticated root-level access available over the network.  (Try `docker run -v /:/host ...` from the client to edit files on the Docker system as root.)  I'd suggest avoiding the remote-Docker setup entirely, unless you're 100% confident you've gotten TLS and other security concerns correct; do your development on the Ubuntu machine with a local Docker.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, You helped me understood the security concerns over the use of remote docker daemon. However, i have found one solution **Remote - WSL** VS Code Extension. With the help of this extension, i can open my SAM application folder in the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) as if my source code is in the linux and i can easily debug my SAM application within the context of linux. [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/07/01/containers-wsl)